# Double "Pipes" in title

Tags: java

At my job today, I was made aware of a little error in our pages' titles. Our site is built using .jsp pages and for the titles of our product pages we use

In our admin (where we can set up the titles for each of the products), we would normally add in * anyone ever run into this issue before, and if so, does anyone know of a way to fix the double pipes issue I have encountered?

Comment: Can you post the code for Strings.toTitleCase?

Comment: Have you determined where the double-pipe is being added? When you debug that line, does the input have only 1 pipe and the output have 2?

Comment: @LouisStephens - `Strings` is not a native Java type. `String` (without the "s" is), but that does not have a `toTitleCase()` method. It is likely a library that is providing the `Strings` class.

Comment: Sorry @beny23, I added the toTitleCase code in my question.

Comment: You are splitting on the occurrence of a space character. If two consecutive spaces were present in the input, I guess you might end up with a |<space>| looking like a two pipes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that the method replaceAll has as the first argument regular expression. The "|" is reserved symbol in regular expressions and you must escape it if you want use it as a string literal. You can create workaround, for example this way.

```
String[] words = str.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  if (words[i].length() > 0) {
    if (!(words[i].substring(0, 1).equals("|"))) {
      sb.append(words[i].replaceFirst(words[i].substring(0, 1), words[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()) + " ");
    } else {
      sb.append(words[i] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nightsorrow. I just tried what you were suggesting, but it seems to actually remove the | all together.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the html escape code for the pipe character `&brvbar;`.

Your title would be:

```
"Monkey Thank You &brvbar; Monkey Thank You Cards"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the fact that `replaceFirst()` takes a regex as parameter and a replacement string. Because you push in the first character as is for the regex parameter, what happens with the vertical bar is (omitting adding to the `StringBuffer`) equivalent to:

```
String addedToBuffer = "|".replaceFirst("|", "|".toUpperCase());
```

What happens then, is that we have a regex which matches the empty string or the empty string. Well, any string matches the empty string regex. So the match gets replaced by "|" (to upper case). So `"|".replaceFirst("|", "|".toUpperCase())` expands to `"||"`. So the `append()` call is given the parameter of `"|| "`.

You can fix your algorithm in two ways:

1. Fix the regex automatically, use literal notation in between `\Q` and `\E`. So your regex to pass to `replaceFirst()` becomes something like `"\\Q"+ literal + "\\E"`.
2. Realise that you do not need regexes in the first place. Instead use two `append()` operations. One to `append()` the case converted *first* character of the item to add, the other to append *the rest*. This looks like this:

   for(String s: items) {
     if(s.equals("")) {
       sb.append(" ");
     }
     else {
       sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)));
       if(s.length() > 1) {
         sb.append(s.substring(1));
       }
       sb.append(" ");
     }
   }

The second approach is probably much easier to follow as well.

PS: For some reason the StackOverflow editor is vehemently disagreeing with code blocks in lists. If someone happens to know how to fix the munged formatting... ?